# Does eating meat along with booze have any benefits?

Tags: preparation-for-drinking

**TL;DR:**

Is eating meat along with booze beneficial? Or does it reduce any adverse effects of drinking?

By drinking, I mean liquors like whisky, vodka or rum. I seldom drink wine.

---

Some optional background on this-

I was advised to eat meat whenever I drink by a person. That advice is common and has probably propagated by word of mouth.

That person (perhaps) exaggerated it further by making a rhyming sort of moral verse like sentence

> "M for *Mod* (booze in my language), "M" for *Mansh* (meat in my language);
>
> "G" for *Ganja* (cannabis in my language) , "G" for *Gakhir* (milk in my language).

I am wondering if the first sentence has any relevance. I eat anything ranging from peanuts, roasted peas, etc. when I drink. Liquors are harsh on the throat, and eating any of those comforts the throat and the mouth. Occasionally, I eat meat as well. I would appreciate any response on if eating meat is better while drinking.

Comment: I have followed this site for a while. I am unsure if this is on-topic. Humble apologies if this is off-topic.

Comment: Random person, how can a person be random?   An unknown person walking down the street comes up and offers unsolicited advice. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness -  OH, wait. Maybe it was Bob Random - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Random  **B for bob in my language**.

Answer (score 1):

**Does eating meat along with booze have any benefits?**

Generally speaking: **no**.

Drinking a little whiskey may be beneficial for the stomach, but would be better somewhat prior to eating.

Even St. Paul ( for those of us who are believers) tells Timothy to drink a little wine because of stomach and frequent ailments.

> Stop drinking only water and use a little wine instead, because of your stomach and your frequent ailments. - [1 Timothy 5:23](https://biblehub.com/1_timothy/5-23.htm)

Drinking in moderation is best. When I am somewhat hungry, I find that one drink will ease my stomach’s wontedness for food if drank about one half hour to an hour before I eat. That includes meat.

> Especially after fatty meals, alcohol is said to promote digestion. But it seems it's not the alcohol that has a positive effect on the stomach. On the contrary: alcohol actually impedes gastric emptying. It blocks the action of nerves that are important for the transport of food in the abdomen. So high-proof alcoholic drinks are not beneficial to digestion. Herbal liqueur **before** a meal can be enjoyable. But here again, it's not the alcohol but the bitter substances the drink contains that stimulate the mucous membranes of the stomach to release acid. That can actually facilitate the pre-digestion of foods. The bitter substances in non-alcoholic beverages such as espresso have a similar effect. The right time for this digestive aid is about half an hour **before** a meal. And after you eat, a postprandial walk is better than any drink. - [Does alcohol after a meal really help digestion?](https://www.dw.com/en/does-alcohol-after-a-meal-really-help-digestion/a-18440111)